# is it possible to use an instance or variable in the subject of rails mailer and how please :)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailer, subject

I would like to use an instance or variable like below in the mailer subject.
So I would like to get the user name or some other user detail in the subject, I tried several thing but I receive an error every time. I can't find documentation about this either.

```
    mail(:to => "test@gmail, :subject => "current_user.name") or "<%= current_user.name %>"


class PositionMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "test@gmail.com"
  layout 'mailer'

  def general_message(position, barge_name)

    @position = position
    @barge_name = barge_name


    mail(:to => "1234@gmail.com, :subject => "#{barge_name}")
  end
end
```

controller

```
  def create
    @position = Position.new(position_params)
    if @position.save!
      redirect_to @position
      PositionMailer.general_message(@position, @barge_name).deliver
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass a variable inside quotes you need to do it like this `"#{variable.value}`

```
:subject => "#{current_user.name}"
```

should do it if it has access to `current_user`

You will have to pass `current_user` to the mailer along with the position value.

So wherever you are calling that from add `current_user`, probably looks something like this.

```
PositionMailer.general_message(position, current_user).deliver
```

Comment: oke i added my mailer, I thought current user could be accessed in any view/controller, or should i define it first in the mailer controller?

Comment: You will have to pass it to the mailer

Comment: so it should be something like:   (i added the post)

Comment: so now when i submit, the subject is empty it says (no subject)  I changed the code again

Comment: where is the `@barge_name` variable being set in your code? I can't see anything in any of those methods that sets it.  If you need to test just fake it first, put `@barge_name = "Test Name"` in the create method and see if it is in the title, and then you can figure out how to set it in the create method dynamically

Comment: Thank a lot! its working now, by replacing test name by current_user.barge_name. Thanks again for your help, i've learned a lot :)